# Does a pod in Kubernetes inherit every kernel settings from its pod?

Tags: kernel, kubernetes

I'm trying to see if my pods are using `tcp_keepalive_time`.

When I ssh into my node and run `sysctl -a` I see that there is value for `tcp_keepalive_time`, but pods don't have them when run the same command in the pod.

In this case, do pods inherit their node's kernel values?

How do I confirm that a pod has its node's kernel value when a pod does not show with `sysctl -a` command?

Answer (score 1):

This official documentation will help you to understand how to set up properties using sysctl in pod: [Setting Sysctls for a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#setting-sysctls-for-a-pod).

You need to use `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time`

Hope this will help you.